# Update/Delete user account in laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5, user-controls, updatepanel

i wana to know how i can let each user can access his/her profile and update user name, email,  password, ets.., and  have another option to delete his/her account in Laravel 5.7, and thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer..you create a controller which serves the details of the user from users table as prerequisite for the blade of profile page, add a button to update, clicking which, the details will be send back to another method of the same controller which will use `update()` method to update the details of the user in users table targetting the correct id and then add a delete button, clicking which, the action will be taken to another method of the same controller by passing the id of the user and use `delete()` method to delete the user from the users table.

simple right?

i dont think you expect the whole code..do you?

Comment: Thank u bro, it's useful.

Comment: pleasure..glad i could help!

Answer (score 0):

This question is more related to CRUD operation.Here you can have two options either you as a admin create their profile using fields like username, email and password or let user sign up in you web application.User can login and edit their profile. As a admin you can list the user and use delete functionality to delete from database.

The below link can be helpful to you to understand more.
[Laravel 5.7 CRUD Example](https://appdividend.com/2018/09/06/laravel-5-7-crud-example-tutorial/)

Comment: Thank you, but i'm using auth controller Auth::routes(); , and when i wanna to update user information this problem face me "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\MethodNotAllowedHttpException "